# String handlings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string

i am having some problem with string handling.

The task is to take an input from user using console with multiple arguments. for eg. user enters the string in the console like below eg:

```
1. test 2 a b 
2. test 3 a b c
3. test 4 a b c d
```

After string "test", the "2" decides how much strings should be ahead. This should be done in single input from console. Like after string 2 there should be "a" and "b" or after "3" there should be "a" "b" "c". 
So right now I'm just defining the fixed command line arguments and the console take that number of string arguments, but I want user to decide in the command line to decide how much string arguments he should pass. Can you please tell me how do I perform the above task mentioned?

Note. I am not using the string.h library of C. There is customised library for string handle.

```
typedef struct S_STRUCT
{
    char*   str;          
    uint_16 strLength;     
    uint_16 bufferLength;   
}stringStruct;


//// this creates a shadow copy from old string which is "test"


#define STRING__CREATE_SCOPY(name,oldString,offset) 

ant_stringStruct01 name = 
{  
    .str=&(oldString)->str[(offset)],
    .strLength=(oldString)->strLength-(offset),  
    .bufferLength= (oldString)->bufferLength(offset)
}


#define LOGGING_CONSOLE_ARG_CREATE(name,size) uint_32 argPool_ ## name [size][2] = {[0 ... (size-1)][0]=0,[0 ... (size-1)][1]=0,}

///start pos of arg
#define LOGGING_CONSOLE_ARG_S(name,argNumber) argPool_ ## name [argNumber][0]

/// len of Args
#define LOGGING_CONSOLE_ARG_L(name,argNumber) argPool_ ## name [argNumber][1]

main ()

{
char *input  = "test"; // basically the input is entered by user during console like "test".` Next step is to compare the user entered string
if(!strncmp(input, "test",4)  // 
STRING__CREATE_SCOPY(localInput, input, 4); // here it creates a shadow copy from 4th position.

LOGGING_CONSOLE_ARG_CREATE(arg, 2);
int cat = &localInput.str[ANT_LOGGING_CONSOLE_ARG_S_01(arg, 0)])

}
```

the problem is now that I can take the string arguments once I have initialised the arg variable. But I want to decide on the console how many argument should I take from the user.

Comment: Declaration/definition of `input` is not  shown. Please provide a [mre].

Comment: the input is entered by user. for e.g. user enters "test" now the next step is to enter next string like (test 2 a b) that takes two strings "a" and "b" only after "2".Similarly (test 3 a b c) takes 3 strings "a" "b" "c" after "3". It is something to do with string pointer handling but I dont know how.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you want command line arguments?

Comment: No question is asked in your question. Questions need to ask questions.

Comment: @Nina yes, I want command line arguments.